Control state space with perturbation
I have a system for which I have two variables that I want to control, let's say the position $x$ and a force $z$. I only know the dynamics of x in the form:
$$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu+Wz$$
where $u$ is my control input (known).
My problem is that I want to control both $x$ and $z$, but I do not know the dynamics of $z$, I only have a relationship between a measured output $y$ and $x$ and $z$ like:
$$y = z + \dot{x}$$
where $y$ is measured but $z$ is not measured directly.
I tried to consider an extended state $\xi = (x,z)$ but I cannot write the model since I do not know $\dot{z}$.
Moroever, I do not really want to consider $z$ as a disturbance because I do not want to reject it but to make it converge towards 0.
I hope this make sense... thanks for your help !

What do the variables $x,u, z$ mean physically? Why is $\dot z$ not known? Why is $z$ not measured? Can $z$ be estimated from $x$ and $u$? Are $x$ and $u$ measured / known? Please [edit] in more details about the problem.

Homework? Solve for z and substitute or sub for x˙. z˙ and z need to be driven to 0? Then what does that mean for x˙ and y?

Since $z$ is not directly measured, you can design a state observer  to estimate $z$. The observer will use measurements of $y$ and the dynamics of $x$ to infer $z$.
An example observer might have the form:
$$
   \hat{z}(t+1) = \hat{z}(t) + L \left( y(t) - \hat{y}(t) \right)
   $$
where $\hat{z}(t)$ is the estimate of $z$, $\hat{y}(t)$ is the predicted output, and $L$ is the observer gain matrix, which you can design using standard observer design techniques and use this estimated state in your control design. Since we don’t have a direct model for $z$, we can then treat it as an unknown state and use extended state formulation say:
$$
   \xi = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ z \end{bmatrix}
   $$
to design the feedback $u(t)$
